# Why do I need to escape < and & when rendering an attribute?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I was reading the documentation for [HtmlAttributeEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8439dd99(v=vs.110).aspx), which as I understand it is intended for use when rendering HTML that appears within double quotes as an attribute, e.g.

```
<INPUT Value="This value must be escaped so that it doesn't contain any quotes">
```

As far as I can tell, the only character I would need to escape would be the double quote.  The browser ought to be able to figure out everything else in that string belongs within the attribute.

Why, then, does the documentation say this?

> The HtmlAttributeEncode method converts only quotation marks ("), ampersands (&), and left angle brackets (<) to equivalent character entities. It is considerably faster than the HtmlEncode method.

And in fact it does escape those, as can be seen by [this poor guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453843/hidden-value-has-html-elements).

is there any reason to escape the < and & characters in this circumstance?  is it required by the HTML5 specification?

With my human eye I can easily see where the delimitation begins and ends in this character sequence:

```
<INPUT value="You & I can both easily see that 5 < 6!">
```

As long as the double quote sequence is properly closed (and double quotes are escaped) I don't understand why the other characters have to be HTML-encoded.

Comment: reason : &nbsp; &lt; &gt; these are HTML encoded strings for blank space, < and >,
browser might think < or > as tags.. hence you should not use them or you have to escape them

Comment: Understood.  However, an attribute contains only a plaintext string, not HTML.  The markup `<INPUT value="I can see clearly that 5<6">` there is no ambiguity where the string begins and ends, and no reason to escape anything.

Comment: unfortunately that's not how browser code works..when it finds an open tag `<` it searches for the next `>`. to close that tag. So when it encounters another '<' it might lead it to think of it as beginning of another tag.

Comment: @Vignesh.N not so true: https://jsfiddle.net/dekelb/8zgp2yjt/ at least chrome displays this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the specs:

> [3.2.3.1 Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attributes)
>
> Except where otherwise specified, attributes on HTML elements may have any string value, including the empty string. Except where explicitly stated, there is no restriction on what text can be specified in such attributes.

According to [specs of `html4`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT), the content of the `value` attribute should be in the type of `cdata`.

From the [HTML Document Representation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html):

> 5.3.2 Character entity references
>
> Four character entity references deserve special mention since they are frequently used to escape special characters:
>
> "`&lt;`" represents the < sign.
> "`&gt;`" represents the > sign.
> "`&amp;`" represents the & sign.
> "`&quot;`" represents the " mark.
>
> Authors wishing to put the "<" character in text should use "`&lt;`" (ASCII decimal 60) to avoid possible confusion with the beginning of a tag (start tag open delimiter). Similarly, authors should use "`&gt;`" (ASCII decimal 62) in text instead of ">" to avoid problems with older user agents that incorrectly perceive this as the end of a tag (tag close delimiter) when it appears in quoted attribute values.
>
> Authors should use "&" (ASCII decimal 38) instead of "&" to avoid confusion with the beginning of a character reference (entity reference open delimiter). **Authors should also use "&" in attribute values since character references are allowed within CDATA attribute values.**

Comment: In addition the XML definition is very similar.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick, thats correct. xhtml (and also html5) are xml-based :)